# Beautiful Soup Table, stop getting info

Tags: python, html, parsing, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

Hey everyone I have some html that I am parsing, here it is:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>

<body>
    <table class="dayinner">
        <tr class="lun">
            <td class="mealname" colspan="3">LUNCH</td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="lun">
            <td class="station">&nbsp;Deli</td>

            <td class="menuitem">
                <div class="menuitem">
                    <input class="chk" id="S1L0000010000047598_35356" onclick=
                    "rptlist(this);" onmouseout="wschk(0);" onmouseover=
                    "wschk(1);" type="checkbox" /> <span class="ul" onclick=
                    "nf('0000047598_35356');" onmouseout="pcls(this);"
                    onmouseover="ws(this);">Made to Order Deli Core</span>
                </div>
            </td>

            <td class="price"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="lun">
            <td class="station">&nbsp;</td>

            <td class="menuitem">
                <div class="menuitem">
                    <input class="chk" id="S1L0000020000046033_63436" onclick=
                    "rptlist(this);" onmouseout="wschk(0);" onmouseover=
                    "wschk(1);" type="checkbox" /> <span class="ul" onclick=
                    "nf('0000046033_63436');" onmouseout="pcls(this);"
                    onmouseover="ws(this);">Chicken Caesar Wrap</span>
                </div>
            </td>

            <td class="price"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="lun">
            <td colspan="3" style="height:3px;"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="lun">
            <td colspan="3" style="background-color:#c0c0c0; height:1px;"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="lun">
            <td class="station">&nbsp;Dessert</td>
            <td class="station">&nbsp;</td>

            <td class="menuitem">
                <div class="menuitem">
                    <input class="chk" id="S1L0000020000046033_63436" onclick=
                    "rptlist(this);" onmouseout="wschk(0);" onmouseover=
                    "wschk(1);" type="checkbox" /> <span class="ul" onclick=
                    "nf('0000046033_63436');" onmouseout="pcls(this);"
                    onmouseover="ws(this);">Chicken Caesar Wrap</span>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the code I have, I want just the items under the deli section, and normally I won't know how many there are is there a way to do this?

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(open("upperMenu.html"))

title = soup.find('td', class_='station').text.strip()

spans = soup.find_all('span', class_='ul')[:2]
```

but this only works if there are two items, how can I have it work if the number of items is unknown?

Thanks in advance

Comment: count all classes with `ul` and pass it through the `find_all()` as parameter?

Comment: My question is if I do not know how many there are, how can I make it so it only gets the <span> under the deli section and not get any under the dessert section

Comment: add another identifier `<span deli class="deli ul"></span>` `soup.find_all('span','deli',class_='ul')[:2]`

Comment: right but this is just a small piece of a large file that changes, is there another way to have it stop getting info when it is done with the deli section?

Comment: do you want to get the `first-child` of class `menuitem`?

Comment: @Viscocent I want to get the item "Made to Order Deli Core" and "Chicken Caesar Wrap", but if there were say 4 items I don't want to have to change the code, I want it to stop either when it see's this code '<td class="station">&nbsp;Dessert</td>', or something along those lines. Thanks for your help so far

Comment: you shouldn't have wrapped both of them in the same table. if you didn't it would be much easier.

Comment: @Viscocent I didn't I am scraping this from the web and it changes daily

Comment: would answering your question with jQuery acceptable?

Comment: @Viscocent Jquery is good too thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `text` attribute in `find_all` function to 1. find all the rows whose station column contains the substring Deli.. 2. Loop through every row and find the spans within that row whose `class` is `ul`.

```
import re
soup = BeautifulSoup(text)

tds_deli = soup.find_all(name='td', attrs={'class':'station'}, text=re.compile('Deli'))

for td in tds_deli:
    try:
        tr = td.find_parent()
        spans = tr.find_all('span', {'class':'ul'})
        for span in spans:
            # do something
            print span.text
        print '------------one row -------------'
    except:
        pass
```

Sample Output in this case:

```
Made to Order Deli Core
------------one row -------------
```

Not sure if I am understanding the problem correctly but I think my code might help you get started.

Comment: that would have been easy if he wanted all that one row, but i think he also want the second row, in short he want's all `span` text  before he find `Dessert`

Comment: @B.Mr.W. yes this is correct all span before dessert if you don't know how many there are? and JQuery would work, thanks